# Relation between the characters of subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let $ H $ and $ K $ be subgroups of a finite group $ G $. Let $ \chi_1(H) $ and $ \chi_1(K) $ denote the trivial characters of $ H $ and  $ K $ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $ 0 $. How "Mackey decomposition"would help us to prove that $ <\chi_1(H)^G, \chi_1(K)^G>_G $ equals the number of $ (H, K) $-bouble cosets

Comment: Do you know [Mackey's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Mackey_decomposition)?

Comment: Yes, bu how can it help?

Comment: If you looked at the link given by Dune you would see how it can help.